# PRAW Why does this recursive function to check if a url is an image return none?

Tags: python, discord.py, praw

I wrote a recursive function to detect whether or not the url of any given post contained "**.jpg**" or "**.png**". But if it doesn't find an image on it's first try, it returns "**None**". If I put a print statement in the function right below the "submission =" it does print out, but the string doesn't seem to exist when I try to return that value. **My goal is to write a function that will always return an image url.** Also I am writing this for a discord bot, so if I should be using async praw let me know.

Thanks.

```
import praw
import random
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id = "CLIENT_ID", client_secret = "CLIENT_SECRET", user_agent= "USER_AGENT")


def is_image():
    submission = random.choice([i for i in reddit.subreddit("RANDOM REDDIT").top("all", limit=100)])
    if ".jpg" in submission.url or ".png" in submission.url:
        return submission.url
    is_image()
    return 
print(is_image())
```

Comment: Only the first try will return `None` to the print statement. All the other tries will return `None` to `is_image()`. Also, only if `jpg` and `png` are _not_ in `submission.url` will `is_image()` be called in line 10.

Comment: Don't use recursion to implement a simple loop. Just use a `while` loop to repeat `random.choice` until the `if` condition is true.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pointlessly calling `is_image()` after the if-statement, you should return it.

```
def is_image():
    submission = random.choice([i for i in reddit.subreddit("RANDOM REDDIT").top("all", limit=100)])
    if ".jpg" in submission.url or ".png" in submission.url:
        return submission.url
    return is_image()

print(is_image())
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, it worked! If you wouldn't mind thought, why was it returning "None" the other way?

Comment: You were calling `is_image` but ignoring *its* return value. Then, `return` with no value implicitly returns `None`.